# Why JEasyUI datagrids load drastically slow?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, jquery-easyui

I've a page with jEasyUI layout and then I've 4 jEasyUI datagrids and one property grid, which are being bound and unbound with 2 or 3 rows of data(different for different grids) based on mouse click on specific spots.

So basically I need to show different set of rows in these grids based on selection which can be performed through mouse click. But the entire bind process is so slow that entire browser seems to hang for few seconds to allow me to make another event(loading new set of rows).

this is how I am binding the jEasyUI grids:

```
$('#gridId1').datagrid({ 
     data: data, 
     onEndEdit: function(){}, 
     onAfterEdit: function(){}, 
     onBeforeEdit:function(){} 
});
```

where `#gridId1` is defined like this:

```
<table border="0" id="gridId1" class="easyui-datagrid" style=""
                   data-options="singleSelect:true,collapsible:true,showHeader:false">
   <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="90%" data-options="field:'Name'">Name</th>
          <th width="10%" field="action" formatter="formatAction">Action</th>
        </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
```

and typical `data` json is like this:

```
var data = {'total':2,'rows':[{Name:'Dummy1'},{Name:'Dummy2'}]}
```

version of jEasyUI - **1.4.1**

Why jEasyUI grids are performing so slow? Is it because I am trying to bind multiple of them just one after another? and internally easyUI controls rely super heavily on `setTimeout` ?

Please help..

Answer (score 1):

EasyUI datagrid has 2 ways of loading (http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/datagrid.php)
One way is though the html and one way through javascript. 
In your case I think you need javascript initialization. 
Right now you use both ways and datagrids are initialized twice.

By this I mean that you should remove the

```
class="easyui-datagrid"
```

and

```
data-options="singleSelect:true,collapsible:true,showHeader:false"
```

Then in the javascript part you should initialize the datagrid like this:

```
$('#gridId1').datagrid({ 
     data: data,
     singleSelect:true,
     collapsible:true,
     showHeader:false,
     onEndEdit: function(){}, 
     onAfterEdit: function(){}, 
     onBeforeEdit:function(){} 
});
```

I hope it helped

Answer (score -1):

rownumbers="true" due to this option the page loading slow drastically. Re

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).